# Ubuntu UEFI Boot

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi, dell

I need your help.
I have ubuntu with dual boot on my machine for a long long time, and a month ago or so I've decided to uninstall windows and let ubuntu be the only OS. That ok, I've erased some partitions with gparted and that's it. But Yesterday I've tried to remove the grub boot screen that asked me if I wanted to log in with ubuntu or windows, I've tried to use the command update-grub well, it does not worked, windows keep being recognized by update-grub. So I've tried to erase one more partition in my hd that was named "Windows Load Managem" well, now I can not boot on my computer, I've installed another partition of ubuntu to see if I could log in, both no positive results come.

My computer is a Dell Inspiron 5558 and originaly came with Windows. I can not boot in because the system UEFI does not show me any option to log in.

I installed this another ubuntu because I've thought that it was fix the boot issue and then i would erase it. Now I dont know what to do...

Answer (score 0):

You never 'remove' the grub boot screen because it is part of the grub bootloader. And Ubuntu can't boot up without its' bootloader (namely grub). You can HIDE the grub boot screen (as display it for zero seconds) by installing and using tweaks of grub-customizer.

My advice would be to clean up all the mess (delete all partitions you don't need) and do a fresh install of Ubuntu. After that, install grub-customizer by opening a Terminal window and type: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install grub-customizer`. The customizer offers you multiple options to play with.

Comment: Hi There, Thanks for the explanation, I will install this customizer when as son as I solve the problem !.

Comment: So, I've installed successfully a ubuntu alongside whit this older installation, but my BIOS(UEFI) does not recognize this new installation either. If I erase the ESP(Efi system partition) the Ubuntu Installation will be able to create a new one? What do you sugest??

Comment: Yes, every operating system (Ubuntu, Windows, or any other) automatically creates the EFI partition (if none detected). EFI partition is required by all EFI hardware. If an EFI partititon is detected by any operating system, the EFI partition will be automatically edited with entries for the new operating system. Easiest way for newbies is to erase entire harddisk and let Ubuntu install automatically. Don't forget to backup personal data to another medium first (cd, external usb device, cloud, GDrive, etc).